# PhoneGap Mac CLI local install failed because of Node version

Tags: macos, node.js, cordova, command-line-interface

So I want to debug my Phonegap webapp locally in Xcode.
I follow the step [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html) and [here](http://phonegap.com/install/), and launch in MAC CLI

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

BUT install failed and CLI result get lots of errors with the first one is :

```
engine phonegap@2.9.0rc1-0.12.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.8","npm":"1.1.59"})
```

I understand my node version is too old : 0.8.8

```
node --version
```

---

I try to update but I am stuck with those 2 methods here and both in errors for me :

**BREW**
Tried Homebrew but did not work :

```
$ brew upgrade node  
Error: node-0.8.8 already installed
```

**NPM**
As I found here
[Upgrading Node.js to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version)
[How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js-npm-and-all-other-dependencies)

```
$ sudo npm install -g n  
$ sudo n stable
sudo: n: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact my bash_profile was missing the path to the n module as I found here:
[cannot install npm? problems generating application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245399/cannot-install-npm-problems-generating-application)

Edit your ~/.bash_profile. Add this export somewhere.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by upgrading node with brew, I just run

```
brew install --upgrade node
```